# How can I shorten URL extentions to make them more friendly

Tags: php, .htaccess

We have links showing like this,

```
turkish-property-world.com/turkey_villas.php?bid=4&page=1
```

would like to show,

```
turkish-property-world.com/turkey_villas
```

in .htaccess we include the rule but nothing changes.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

any help?

Comment: You cant put away the GET parameters.

Comment: Without the `bid=4` and `page=1` how are you going to know what the user is look for/what page they want?

Comment: we have a page navigation 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 etc. we have a duplicate content issue with google quality guidlines where we need to make all show one address

Comment: @antalya You need to keep bid and p parameters too. You can see my answer for further details

Comment: Question is how are you going to load your page with `bid` and `page` parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following;

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ $1.php?bid=$2&page=$3 [L]
```

By doing this,

```
turkish-property-world.com/turkey_villas.php?bid=4&page=1
```

will be

```
turkish-property-world.com/turkey_villas/4/1
```

You need to kep other parameters too

**Update:** Above rule will work not just only `turkey_villas`, will work for other *.php names

Comment: thanks for the reply. i inserted the above but it still shows the same. also what does this mean i didn't understand --You need to kep other parameters too. thks

Answer (score 2):

There is a Javascript solution, which is simple, but not very elegant. Still:

```
//get the url
$old_url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

//remove everything after '.php' in the url
$new_url = substr($old_url, 0, strpos($old_url, '.php'));

//then with javascript you replace the url with the new one
<script type="text/javascript">
   if(new_url != '')
   {
      window.history.replaceState({"html":'Title',"pageTitle":'Page Title'}, '', new_url);
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^turkey_villas$ villas.php?bid=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
```

In "villas.php" file get the bid like this $_GET['bid'];